# WPDB SQL Ignore `post_status` Parameter

Tags: wpdb, sql

I use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wp_posts.post_status != 'draft'
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 17
        OR wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 18
        OR wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 19
    ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC 
    LIMIT 6 
    OFFSET 6
```

but result of this show posts that have `post_status = draft`.

Why this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you use `where post_status = 'publish'`. So you wouldnt need to explicitly tell the drafts not to show up by using `wp_posts.post_status != 'draft'`

I think, your SQL says somthing like:

> Grab all posts which are published and not drafted and attached to
>   term_id 17 **OR** grab all posts which are attached to term_id 18
>   **OR** grab all posts which are attached to term_id 19.

So you should use some brackets to say something like

> Grab all posts which are published and either attached to term_id 17 or term_id 18 or
>   term_id 19

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN 
    wp_term_relationships ON (
        wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    wp_term_taxonomy ON (
        wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    ) 
WHERE (
    wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND 
    wp_posts.post_status='publish' AND 
    (
        wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 17 OR wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 18 OR wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 19 
    )
)
ORDER BY 
    post_date_gmt DESC 
    LIMIT 6 
    OFFSET 6
```